# Show that $P:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ by $P(x_1,...,x_k)=\sum_{(i_1,...,i_k)\in I}c(i_1,...,i_k)x_1^{i_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot x_k^{i_k}$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $k\geq 1$, let $I$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}^k$ and let $c:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Show that $P:\mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ by $P(x_1,...,x_k)=\sum_{(i_1,...,i_k)\in I}c(i_1,...,i_k)x_1^{i_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot x_k^{i_k}$ is continuous.

So for base case $k=1$ I have:

$P:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $P(x)=\sum_{i\in I} c(i)x^i$ is just a polynomial which are continuous.

So assume that this holds for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Then I want to prove that $P(x_1,...,x_{k+1})=\sum_{(i_1,...,i_{k+1})\in I}c(i_1,...,i_{k+1})x_1^{i_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot x_k^{i_{k+1}}$ is continuous

I think the sum means for example if $k=2$ then $P(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in I} c(i,j)x_1^i x_2^j$?

I want to say then that since the function $c(i_1,...,i_{k+1})$ is a function on a discrete space, it is continuous, and since $x^i$ is continuous for each $i\in I$ then I can use that the product of continuous functions is continuous, to show that each $c(i_1,...,i_{k+1})x_1^{i_1}\cdot\cdot\cdot x_k^{i_{k+1}}$ is continuous, and the sum of continuous functions is continuous then $P$ is continuous.

The hint for the question says to use that the direct sum of continuous functions is continuous, but I don't see how that relates to this function since it's from $X^k\to \mathbb{R}$, unless I'm not interpreting the notation correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x_1,x_2,...,x_k) \to x_i$ is continuous for each $i$ and thus implies $(x_1,x_2,...,x_k) \to x_i^{j}$ is continuous for all $i $ and $j$. any constant multiple of this also continuous and finite sum of continuous functions is continuous. That finishes the proof.

Example: $x_1x_2^{2}-5x_1^7x_2^{9}$ is obtained by adding $x_1x_2^{2}$ and $-5x_1^7x_2^{9}$. The first terms is continuous because it is the product of $x_1$ and $x_2^{2}$. Similarly the second term is also continuous.

Comment: So was my interpretation of the notaion for $P$ incorrect? The $k$ determines how many variables there are but you don't need every combination of powers from $I$?

Comment: Your argument for continuity of $c(i_1,..i_{k+1})$ does not make sense. We are talking about continuity of $P$ as a function of $x_1,x_2,..,x_k$.